# Cannot populate DataGrid rows in user control's DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a problem while trying to populate a **DataGrid** inside my User Control which is embedded on parent **DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate**. The **child DataGrid** (which is inside the user control) should populate the related information inherited from its parent DataGrid. Somehow it doesn't work as expected. But when I'm trying to bind a **Text Block** within my child user control, it works! Hope someone can help me with this:-)

Thanks a lot

This is my parent DataGrid:

```
 <Custom:DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin="10,10,10,12"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
                     AlternationCount="2"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     EnableColumnVirtualization="false"
                     EnableRowVirtualization="false"
                     IsReadOnly="False"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ChangeOverData}"
                     RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ChangeOverDetailsSelected,
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            Source={StaticResource GridOverviewViewModel}}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     SelectionUnit="FullRow">

        <Custom:DataGrid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#F7BFEE86" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.966" Color="#13A7E4FF" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Custom:DataGrid.Background>
        <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">

                <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Name="btnWIP"
                                    Width="20"
                                    Height="20"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridOverviewViewModel},
                                                      Path=ButtonReloadWIPDetails}"
                                    Content="WIP"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource RoundGlassButton}">

                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StartDate,
                                                         StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"
                                       Header="StartDate"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MacNo}"
                                       Header="MacNo"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PosNo}"
                                       Header="Pos"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />

            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Position}"
                                       Header="Position"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />

            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CurMO}"
                                       Header="CurrentMO"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />

            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NextMO}"
                                       Header="NextMO"
                                       IsReadOnly="True">

                <Custom:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding MOFontColor}" />
                    </Style>
                </Custom:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </Custom:DataGridTextColumn>


        </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
        <Custom:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <local:DataGridRowDetails x:Name="CODetails"
                    />

            </DataTemplate>
        </Custom:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

        <Custom:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Custom:DataGridRowsPresenter />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </Custom:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </Custom:DataGrid>
```

And this is my child user controls - which contains another DataGrid

```
<Custom:DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"
                     Width="Auto"
                     Margin="0,0,0,45"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     AlternatingRowBackground="Azure"
                     AlternationCount="2"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                     >

        <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>

            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FIF}"
                                       Header="FIF"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />

            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MacNo}"
                                       Header="MacNo"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />

            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NomQty}"
                                       Header="NomQty"
                                       IsReadOnly="True" />

        </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>

    </Custom:DataGrid>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1"
               Width="85"
               Height="23"
               Margin="3,83,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Text="{Binding Path=NextMO}"                   
               />
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right at all:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

Or are your items actually collections themselves? If not you better specify a path to the internal collections.

Comment: do you mean this one? : ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid, AncestorLevel=1}}". I've done it but no luck :-(

Comment: @anevil: No! I don't know what your data looks like (you might want to add a class signature), but that is not a good idea. You should just target a property for the sub-items which presumably exists on the items.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. From my understanding you are telling me that the column must be bind with the items populated within the parent datagrid right? yes actually I also have try it out but still not displaying aything. And just fyi, the FIF,MacNo and NomQty is actually exist in the data source (ChangeOverData = a ListCollectionView from my viewmodel). The parent datagrid populated as expected but the problem is now on its child. Hope this will make it clearer :-)

Comment: @anevil: No, i am telling you that the `ItemsSource` binding does not work, i never said anything about columns. **What are the items you want to use in the row details datagrid?**

Comment: the item will be a user control with a data grid inside..is it the one you are expecting for? ;-)

Comment: Re-read my question, i already know that you have a usercontrol with a datagrid...

Comment: the items will be part of the parent datagrid source (ChangeOverData).Like I said I've try to bind it with TextBlock and the user control display the parent's **NextMO** it successfully

Comment: @anevil: Why would you want the same items in the details of one item?

Comment: there are 2 data to be compared [example CurMO and NextMO]. both record being retrieved in the same row. I've decided to separate them by displaying them as 2 rows of data in order to avoid too many columns in the datagrid and to make it easier for comparison

Comment: @anevil: Anyway, if you want to target the same collection as the parent DataGrid you could try a binding like this: `{Binding DataContext.ChangeOverData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}`, you could use some [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to get the items you want.

Comment: @anevil: Try to [debug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) it then...